# Python Turtle, change visible part

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

On the canvas,I draw two dots,right one is at `(100,0)`,left one is at `(-1000,0)`.After initializing the program,the orginal screen location(visible part) is near the right dot,just like  pic1 show

pic 1:[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtPRN.png

And now I wanna move the the screen(visible part) to the left dot **using coordinate** so that i can see it(pic2).What should I do?

pic 2:https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rtfrv.png

```py
def drawDot(x):
    penup()
    goto(x, 0)
    pendown()
    dot('pink')
    write(x)


b = -1000 #left dot(-1000,0)

a = 100   #right dot(100,0)

speed(0)
delay(0)
tracer(0, 0)
hideturtle()
screensize(500,500)

color('red')
bgcolor('black')

drawDot(a)
drawDot(b)
done()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the following does what you describe.  When the window opens, it's centered on `(0, 0)` and point `a` is visible off to the right and point `b` isn't visible at all.  When you click on the window, it scrolls so that the window is centered on point `b`:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT = 500, 500
CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT = 3000, 1000

def drawDot(x):
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.setx(x)
    turtle.dot('pink')
    turtle.write(x)

def scrollToDot(x, y):  # unused arguments
    canvas = screen.getcanvas()
    # tkinter has a different coordinate system
    # we have to describe left edge of scrolled
    # window as percentage in its coordinates:
    screen_center = CANVAS_WIDTH / 2
    dot_center = screen_center + b
    left_edge = dot_center - screen.window_width() / 2
    canvas.xview_moveto(left_edge / CANVAS_WIDTH)  # percentage

a = 100  # right dot(100, 0)
b = -1000 # left dot(-1000, 0)

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT)  # What we see
screen.screensize(CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT)  # What there is
screen.bgcolor('black')

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.speed('fastest')
turtle.color('red')

drawDot(a)
drawDot(b)

screen.onclick(scrollToDot)
screen.mainloop()
```

To do this, we have to access the tkinter `Canvas` underpinnings of turtle.  However, the `Canvas` coordinate system is different than turtle's, so we have to make an adjustment as noted in the code comments.

Comment: Wow,this is what I exactly wanna realize.Very appreciate.